# find out previous caller

Tags: solidity

assuming the following scenario:

a user A calls a function in contract CA which in turn calls a function in contract CB which call a function in contract CC

I would like to discover who called CB within CC. User a is the `tx.origin`. Is there a way to get the call stack from within a function?

Comment: Right here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73103/who-is-msg-sender-in-a-nested-call-chain

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately Solidity can't provide the caller of the caller.

If you control CB you could of course have it pass its `msg.sender` as a parameter of its call to CC.