# Who is msg.sender when function calls a function within the same contract?

Tags: msg.sender

So yeah, who is the msg.sender if a function calls another function within the same contract?

```
contract A {
    function doSomething() {
        do2();
        //msg.sender == the user
    }
    
    function do2() {
        //is msg.sender the user, or address(this) = this contract?
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you call it as an external

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the same `msg.sender` in both cases, which is the user. The caller does not change when the context does not leave the contract.

I recommend you try the contract you wrote on [Remix](http://remix.ethereum.org).

And you also take a look at this thread: [Who is msg.sender in a nested call chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73103/who-is-msg-sender-in-a-nested-call-chain/73104#73104).

**Update**: as Majd mentioned in the comments, if you call the function as external, with the `.call` function, the `msg.sender` would be the contract itself.